# How do I remove my email from a CommCare project space?

Tags: commcare

I want to unlink my email account from a project space, but I can't figure out how to do that.  My email does not have the "Remove Membership" button next to it on the web users page.  I've also tried to go to My Account -> My Projects, but there doesn't seem to be a way to remove it there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you cannot remove your own membership from a project space. You will need to ask someone else (another admin) to do it for you.

One reason I see behind this is to prevent people from accidentally removing themselves from a project space.